# cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'staff' - Cannot validate xml against a xsd

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I can't validate xml document against xsd schema.

And I couldn't figure out what is wrong there.

Here is `xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<staff xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="employee.xsd">
    <employee>
        <name>Carl Cracker</name>
        <salary>75000</salary>
        <hiredate year="1987" month="12" day="15" />
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Harry Hacker</name>
        <salary>50000</salary>
        <hiredate year="1989" month="10" day="1" />
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Tony Tester</name>
        <salary>40000</salary>
        <hiredate year="1990" month="3" day="15" />
    </employee>
</staff>
```

And `xsd` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="staff">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="employee" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="name"/>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:int" name="salary"/>
              <xsd:element name="hiredate">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:simpleContent>
                    <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                      <xsd:attribute type="xsd:short" name="year" use="optional"/>
                      <xsd:attribute type="xsd:byte" name="month" use="optional"/>
                      <xsd:attribute type="xsd:byte" name="day" use="optional"/>
                    </xsd:extension>
                  </xsd:simpleContent>
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

And output is next:

```
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'staff'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredTextImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element
    at com.lab.edu.DOMTreeParser.parseStaff(DOMTreeParser.java:77)
    at com.lab.edu.DOMTreeParser.<init>(DOMTreeParser.java:42)
    at com.lab.edu.Application.main(Application.java:7)
```

Here is snippet of code:

```
public DOMTreeParser(String filename) {
    employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean result = validate(filename);
    System.out.println("it is validate result: " + result);

    if (result == false) {
        System.out.println("XML isn't valid");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    // if all are correct - parse xml
    parseStaff(document.getDocumentElement());
}

private boolean validate(String filename) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setValidating(true);
        factory.setAttribute(JAXP_SCHEMA_LANGUAGE, W3C_XML_SCHEMA);
        factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);

        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        builder.setErrorHandler(new SimpleErrorHandler());

        document = builder.parse(new File(filename));

        return true;
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I tried to validate xml accord xsd at [validator](http://www.corefiling.com/opensource/schemaValidate.html) - all was valid.

What is cause of this `cvs..` message?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outermost element of your instance document must match a global element declaration in the schema. You only have one global element declaration, for the "staff" element, which is not present in your instance. If you want the "employee" element to validate, you will have to promote it from a local element declaration to a global one, which means rewriting the schema as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="staff">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="employee" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="employee">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="name"/>
              <xsd:element type="xsd:int" name="salary"/>
              <xsd:element name="hiredate">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:simpleContent>
                    <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                      <xsd:attribute type="xsd:short" name="year" use="optional"/>
                      <xsd:attribute type="xsd:byte" name="month" use="optional"/>
                      <xsd:attribute type="xsd:byte" name="day" use="optional"/>
                    </xsd:extension>
                  </xsd:simpleContent>
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: I tried this one, but result is the same. Can you suggest any tool for generating `xsd` from xml file? I tried one - trang, but it looks too difficult for human understanding.

Comment: Sorry, my response is quite wrong. I think your schema is OK and the problem is in your Java code. I don't have time to debug that for you, sorry.